# Excel VBA 2016 - Auto_Open does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automatically run a macro upon opening the workbook but it's not working. I had no issues with it for 2010, I am currently using 2016.

Below is the code. I also tried `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`.

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'MsgBox "hey"
Run FlipDaScript
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'MsgBox "hey"
Application.Quit
End Sub`
```

When I open the workbook, it has the following error window text and does not run anything:

"Compile error in hidden module: Mainscript. this error commonly occurs when code is incompaticle with the version, platform, or architecture of this application. Click "Help" for information on how to correct this error."

I couldn't find anything on this, I apologize if it has been asked already.
Any information on how to correct this or use a different method is appreciated.

Comment: Place the is code in the `Workbook_Open` event of the `ThisWorkbook` module. Does it work there? (You said you put it in `Workbook_Close` ... which is different than `Workbook_Open` and I assume it's *not* a typo. If it's not that, could be in `FlipDaScript`. Test by commenting out that line and seeing if runs by uncommenting out `Msgbox`

Comment: I did try that. That was typo on my side, it has been updated. I Tried both `Private Sub Workbook_Open` and `Sub Workbook_Open`. Received the same error message. The only difference was that it said the error was now in hidden module: ThisWorkbook.

Comment: Replace `Run FlipDaScript` by `Call FlipDaScript`.

Comment: Wow, feeling really stupid here. That was it, Excelosaurus! sorry about that.